# d3.js inner bubble chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]

I am working on a bubble chart that needs to look like this - its likely to have just 2 series.

My main concern is what to do - if the bubbles are of the same size or if the situation is reversed.

I thought of using this jsfiddle as a base..

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1450/

```
// generate data with calculated layout values
var nodes = bubble.nodes(data)
  .filter(function(d) {
     return !d.children;
  }); // filter out the outer bubble


var vis = svg.selectAll('circle')
  .data(nodes);

vis.enter()
  .insert("circle")
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
  })
  .attr('r', function(d) {
    return d.r;
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.name);
  })
  .attr('class', function(d) {
    return d.className;
  });

vis
  .transition().duration(1000)

vis.exit()
  .remove();
```

Comment: --- I've come up with this fiddle -- but then the bubbles are not inside each other -- http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1547/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly updated your first fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/09fsu0v4/1/

So, lets go through your questions:

1. a bubble chart that needs to look like this - its likely to have just 2 series.

   Bubble charts as part of pack layout rely on data structure - nested JSON with `children` array. Each node could be either root node (container) or leaf node (node that represents some end value). And its role depends on 'children' value presence. (https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Pack-Layout.md#nodes)

   So, to get you chart looking like on picture just re-arrange json structure (or write children accessor function - https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Pack-Layout.md#children). Brief example is in updated fiddle.
2. if the bubbles are of the same size or if the situation is reversed

   Parent nodes (containers) size is sum of all child nodes size. So if you have only one child node parent node will have the same size.
   As far as you can't directly change parent node size - situation with oversized child nodes is impossible.

Comment: 1) how would create this child accessor function. Also what could be done in terms of animations - if they could grow, shrink, move/shake

Comment: > _pack.children([children])_
If children is specified, sets the specified children accessor function. If children is not specified, returns the current children accessor function, which by default assumes that the input data is an object with a children array

https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Pack-Layout.md#children

Comment: Animations is more broad question. Actually d3 can animate(visualize) any changes of data and corresponding DOM elements values (height, width, radius, color, opacity, etc.) So answer is - yes, they can grow shrink, move/shake.

Here is pretty simple example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/b07f8ae91c5e9e45719c

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier if you start with [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530) instead. 
You could set the smaller bubble to be a child of the larger one.

As for when the series have the same size, I would either have a single bubble with both series given the same color, or I would separate the two bubbles. There isn't really much you can do when the bubbles need to be the same size.